# Back up and restore a Core Data SQLite (core data)

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have searched everywhere on SO Google etc and I can't seem to find a  solution or tutorial that fits for manually backing up, and restoring my Core Data Sqlite files.  The aim is for the user to manually restore the Core Data SQlite files from the documents directory.

[This seems promising](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/sample-apps-explanations/backup-files/) but is just to complex for my needs or to extrapulate the relevant sections to my issue.  I just want to replicate want iCloud does by backing up the documents directory without the user having to restore the device to a back up every time they may need their data back.  I was hoping cloudkit in iOS 8 would make this simpler but nothing has clicked so far.

To summarise: How do I get the contents of the documents directory up to iCloud, then retrieve it again.  Im not after syncing, just remote storage and retrieval of the documents directory. Ive read some people have had success with Dropbox for this, open to that to

**UPDATE**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite"];
        NSString *filePath2 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite-shm"];
        NSString *filePath3 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCertifi.sqlite-wal"];

//Path to documents directory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/files.zip"];

        //Zip up documents directory
        ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
        [archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
        [archiver addFileToZip:filePath newname:@"backUp.sqlite"]; 
        [archiver addFileToZip:filePath2 newname:@"backUp.sqlite-shm"];
        [archiver addFileToZip:filePath3 newname:@"backUp.sqlite-wal"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done iCloud documents, CloudKit and Dropbox.

Dropbox is the easiest to start with.

I zip up my database:

```
ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
[archiver addFileToZip:withPath newname:filename]; //@"x.sqlite"
[archiver addFileToZip:withPath newname:filename]; //@"x.sqlite-shm"
[archiver addFileToZip:withPath newname:filename]; //@"x.sqlite-wal"
```

Then send it up to dropbox

```
NSString *dropBoxPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@",kBackupFolder,fileToUpload];
DBPath *path = [[DBPath alloc] initWithString:dropBoxPath];
NSString *sourcePath = xxxxx;
if (!info) {
    DBFile *backupFile = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:path error:&createFileError];
    DBError *writeFileError;
    [showFile writeContentsOfFile:sourcePath shouldSteal:NO error:&writeFileError];
```

You can wait for it to upload:

```
while (showFile.status.state == DBFileStateUploading || showFile.status.error) {
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
fileprogress = showFile.status.progress;
```

Links:

https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync

Comment: Thanks for reply, Ive tried what you suggested (code updated) however the zip wont open when on desktop, also the sqlite files are not a copy of the documents directory simply new empty files.  Im interested in  how you are retrieving them back from dropbox and deleting your existing database?  This can be done manually in iTunes sharing but its not very elegant

Comment: If the files are empty, you don't have the right filename (you need the full path), you might want to: NSAssert([NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistAtPath:xxxx],@"File must exist");

Comment: Hi, as this old question, I'm just wondering how did you go about your issue, I'm currently doing exactly the same, however, my issue is the zipped file want open, when I restore it or even on the desktop; although I'm using the same zipping library mentioned in the above answer.